# implementing iterator with iterable to Hashmap - is it possible?

Tags: java, hashmap, iterable

How can I create an Iterator (by implementing iterable) to Hashmap if it doesn't preserve order?
my keys should be ordered.. and I want to iterate in descending order

Comment: You can iterate over the entry set.

Comment: `Iterator` itself says nothing about order, it just iterates over the elements of a collection.

Comment: keep in mind hash tables achieve their speed by NOT keeping the keys in order; if you want ordering, use TreeMap or something like that

Comment: i tried using tree map.. but it doesn't have get(index)method

Comment: @Shiran [`Map`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) doesn't have `get(index)` method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a [`TreeMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html) maybe:

> The map is sorted according to the natural ordering of its keys

Also, from `TreeMap.keySet()` documentation:

> Returns a Set view of the keys contained in this map. The set's iterator returns the keys **in ascending order**

---

Iteration example:

```
TreeMap<K,V> tree;
// ...
for (final String key : tree.keySet()) {
    final V value = tree.get(key);
}
```

Comment: how do i iterate it if i don't have the method get(index)?

Comment: You do have a [`get()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html#get%28java.lang.Object%29)

Comment: do I get the keys as Set? is it ordered Set?

Comment: @Shiran That's what the `TreeMap.keySet()` excerpt I copied in my answer says.

Comment: i want to implement iterable interface.. will the declaration be "private class myIterator implements Iterator<K> "
?

Comment: @Shiran Yes, it would look something like that

Answer (score 1):

It is true that `HashMap` doesn't preserve insertion order. But, you might use [`LinkedHashMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html) of which the Javadoc says (in part)

> Hash table and linked list implementation of the `Map` interface, with predictable iteration order.

Comment: @Shiran Correct (like a `HashMap`) it has [`get(Object key)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html#get%28java.lang.Object%29). Your question said `HashMap`, not `List`.

Comment: so basically its the same implementation of linked list, just using get(object key)?

Comment: The second sentence in the first Javadoc link says *This implementation differs from HashMap in that it maintains a doubly-linked list running through all of its entries.* There is also a [`TreeMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html) (which is sorted by the keys).

Answer (score 0):

You can copy the entries from the `HashMap` to a collection that preserves order (like a `List`) and then sort them based on the keys (in reverse order). You say that you want to sort the keys in descending order, so I assume that the key implements `Comparable` but since I don't know what the type is of your key, I used type parameters `K` and `V` as placeholders.

```
    Map<K, V> map = new HashMap<>();
    List<Map.Entry<K, V>> list = new ArrayList<>(map.entrySet());
    Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<Map.Entry<K, V>>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Entry<K, V> o1, Entry<K, V> o2) {
            Comparable k1 = (Comparable) o1.getKey();
            Comparable k2 = (Comparable) o2.getKey();
            return -k1.compareTo(k2);
        }
    });
```